# Display online users in server/client chat using socket programming

Tags: java, sockets

While working on a server-client simple chat application I've encounterd in an issue.
I can't figure out how to display online users to the connected clients.

The server has a string vector containing each of the connected users name.
On the client I have a Textarea of online users which I want to display the current connected users ofcourse.

Since code is a bit lengthy, I'll post it using pastebin.

[Server Code](http://pastebin.com/761Yx93g)

[Client Code](http://pastebin.com/EmgpdRXJ)

I think it's might be importent to mention, the server and the client are in different projects.

Comment: why not clients.size() ?

Comment: this is not a question for SO, you are not elaborating on what's blocking you

Comment: I will re-ask the question and will try to be more accurate regarding the issues I'm having. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the server has to send the information to the client.  Whether the client should ask the server to send the info, or the server should send it spontaneously (e.g. when other clients connect or disconnect, or periodically) is up to you to decide.